# Поле с интерфейсом в инспекторе unity

Tags: unity3d

```
class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
     [SerializeField] private ISpawner _spawner;
}
```

Не отображается в инспекторе поле с интерфейсом. Погуглил, и выяснил, что unity не умеет использовать интерфейс, для этого можно использовать абстрактный класс. Но вот вопрос! Почему это нельзя сделать, если, скачав плагин Odin, у меня все заработало. Делаю вывод, что если разработчики этого пакета смогли решить эту проблему, то значит это возможно. Вопрос, как это сделать?

Comment: Так интерфейс наследует не экземпляр класса, а весь класс. То есть реализация интерфейса прописывается в коде класса. Может в вашем случае стоит использовать наследование от абстрактного класса, как вы, кстати, и пишете в вопросе? Это более логично с точки зрения ООП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один буквально не просто так стоит деньги, все что они сделали это огромное количества труда. Они не только написали `Drawer`, рисующий `ObjectField` в инспекторе, но ещё и сериализатор, потому что сами по себе ссылочные типы не сериализуются, только их значения если они `[Serializable]`, а уж ссылка на ассет юнити тем более.

Я не пользуюсь одином, вместо этого я просто написал атрибут, не позволяющий назначать через инспектор, без требуемого интерфейса для `ObjectReference` полей (`GameObject` и `ScriptableObject`).

```
[SerializeField, RequireInterface(IFoo)] private GameObject _fooObjContainer;
[SerializeField, RequireInterface(IFoo)] private ScriptableObject _fooScrObjContainer;
private IFoo _foo;

private void Awake () 
{
    _foo = _fooObjContainer.GetComponent<IFoo>();
    // или
    _foo = _fooScrObjContainer as IFoo;
}
```

---

```
public class RequireInterface : PropertyAttribute
{
    public readonly Type RequireType;

    public RequireInterface (Type requireType)
    {
        RequireType = requireType;
    }
}
```

---

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(RequireInterface))]
public class RequireInterfaceDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        RequireInterface requireInterface = attribute as RequireInterface;
        Type requireType = requireInterface.RequireType;
        if (IsValid(property, requireType))
        {
            label.tooltip = "Require "+requireInterface.RequireType+" interface";
            CheckProperty(property, requireType);
        }
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);
    }

    private bool IsValid (SerializedProperty property, Type targetType)
    {
        return targetType.IsInterface && property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference;
    }

    private void CheckProperty (SerializedProperty property, Type targetType)
    {
        if (property.objectReferenceValue == null)
            return;
        if (property.objectReferenceValue as GameObject)
            CheckGameObject(property, targetType);
        else if (property.objectReferenceValue as ScriptableObject)
            CheckScriptableObject(property, targetType);
    }

    private void CheckGameObject (SerializedProperty property, Type targetType)
    {
        GameObject field = property.objectReferenceValue as GameObject;
        if (field.GetComponent(targetType) == null)
        {
            property.objectReferenceValue = null;
            Debug.LogError("GameObject must contain component implemented "+ targetType+" interface");
        }
    }

    private void CheckScriptableObject (SerializedProperty property, Type targetType)
    {
        ScriptableObject field = property.objectReferenceValue as ScriptableObject;
        Type fieldType = field.GetType();
        if (targetType.IsAssignableFrom(fieldType) == false)
        {
            property.objectReferenceValue = null;
            Debug.LogError("ScriptableObject must implement "+ targetType+" interface");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На счёт odin'а понял. Ваше решение интересное, и лучше использовать что-то такое, чем тянуть все тулзы из Одина ради одних интерфейсов. Но меня отпугивает вот это нагромождение в awake. Выходит, что мне в каждом классе придется такую делать. + еще 1 поле для обьекта, а потом уже и для интерфейса. Но за ответ спасибо, очень доступно и понятно!

Comment: Тогда уже лучше, наверное, использовать абстрактный класс. Как вы считаете?

Comment: "Нагромождение" в две строчки, по мне пугать не должно, меня скорее раздражает их нейминг, поскольку они суть одно но называть их нужно по разному . На тему абстрактного класса это могло бы помочь в данной ситуации, но с точки зрения хороших практик программирования это ужасный косяк, инверсия зависимостей должна реализовываться через интерфейсы, а цель абстрактных классов в полиморфизме, поэтому лично для меня это неприемлемо, но тем кому в данной ситуации на это насрать, я их понимаю .

Comment: А ну ещё существует альтернатива в виде `Zenject` суть которого создание `DI` в проекте в виде контейнеров.